# vb.net 4.0 iif issue when there is a parameter set

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-4.0

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?  the page should "YES This is a test"

```
Partial Public Class testForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private Property test() As String
        Get
            'if is in session, return it, otherwise look it up
            If (IsNothing(Session("test"))) Then
                Session("test") = ""
            End If

            Return Session("test")

        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            Session("test") = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Istest As Boolean
        Get
            IIf(test.Contains("yes"), True, False)

        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        test = "yes"
        Response.Write(IIf(Istest, "YES This is a test", "NO testing here"))

    End Sub



End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a Return in Istest:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Istest As Boolean
    Get
        Return IIf(test.Contains("yes"), True, False)
    End Get
End Property
```

Two tips about your code.

1. Use [If() operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) instead of Iif, it works the same way but uses short-circuit evaluation. There is no reason I can think of to prefer Iif() over If().
2. You don't actually need to use If or Iif at all in your IsTest property:

---

```
Public ReadOnly Property Istest As Boolean
    Get
        Return test.Contains("yes")
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: +1, but even better, just: `Return test.Contains("yes")` No IIf() needed.